# mu-query for finding mails with a single and specific recipient (mu4e)

Tags: mu4e

Using **mu4e**, I'm looking for the regex to display mails that have been sent to one specific recipient, and only one recipient (i.e. no cc:, no other name in the to: field). For example, if I use mu4e search and type `to:john@doe.com` as a regex, mu4e will display all mails addressed to `john@doe.com` but also mails addressed to both `john@doe.com` and `jane@doe.com` (jane might be in the **to:** or **cc:** field in some mails). I would like instead to find mails that are only addressed to `john@doe.com`.

What would be the right regex for such query using mu4e?

Comment: If you're asking know how to include arbitrary literal text in a regexp (in elisp code), then see `C-h f regexp-quote`.  Note also that `.` is special in regexp syntax, so is one of the characters which would be escaped by regexp-quote.

Comment: If you're asking "how can I match `to:john@doe.com` without also matching the likes of `to:john@doe.commerce.com`?" then you want to use `$` or `\'` at the end of your pattern (which respectively match the end of any line and the absolute end of the text being searched).

Comment: Can you update the question to explain how you get to the point where you need a regexp?  It's not clear to me what you're actually doing.

Comment: I modified the question and tried to be more precise with my example.

Comment: I do understand that you're looking for a mu database query and not specifically a regexp. You may need regexps to achieve your goal, but the title and explanations are somewhat misleading.

Comment: Good point, I changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding you're looking for a *mu query* (and not exactly a *regexp*) which will find emails that:

- has `to:`*email*
  **AND**
- has no other `recip:` field

so something like this will do it:

```
to:my@email.com (not cc:/.+/  not bcc:/.+/)
```

please, note that:

- neither `mu-query` or `mu4e` manuals covers how to search for an empty field, so I faked it using any content regexp, use whatever one fits you better.
- logical operators and its grouping for excluding things can be tricky. In this case `AND` is implicit, that may not fit perfectly your use case. Anyway you'll get the idea.
- `recip:` fields can be a list of addresses, if you want to cover a list in `to:` extra work will be required.

  ---

  **Edit** using `mu-guile` you can retrieve any field entirely and do custom processing instead checking against an index, but that will take things out of mu4e.

  ---
- `mu4e-headers-include-related` may fool you, disable it or press <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle inclusion in your search results.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't prevent the case of multiple addresses in the `to` field, does it?

Comment: not as it is, for such thing you'll need a more elaborated `to:` query. But I don't know if mu-query is able to tell apart if a message has more than one value in a given field beyond matching or not, neither how it can do it, as there is no example of such thing in any manual. Might be a worthy issue in github.

Comment: @Nicolas Rougier: Maybe write a search regexp in to: that would only match if there is a single character `@`?